# How to get an 'active travel' network on OSMNX?

Tags: osmnx

Is it possible to obtain a network in OSMNX that includes **both** walking and cycling networks as one?

Look at this example (Amsterdam):

Walking `network_type='walk'`
[WalkingNetwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqOBH.png)

Cycling `network_type='bike'`[CyclingNetwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJbMc.png)

One over the other (to be able to see the differences) [BothNetworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6NHj.png)

Is it possible to have a "unified, integrated and clean" network with both travel modes?

Thanks